# JavaScript localStorage for pacman game

Tags: javascript, arrays, box2d, pacman

I'm trying to learn how use the `localStorage` for a pacman game.

The idea is one pacman eats a pellet which deletes it from page and adds it to `localStorage` so you refresh the page to pellet are still gone.

My problem is that only getting last Key Id from key list back, but what I want is an array to store all numbers and get them all back.

My code is below:

```
for (var j in key_list) {
keyId = key_list[j].GetUserData().val;
stage.removeChild(pacdotsE[keyId]);
world.DestroyBody(key_list[j]);
//console.log(keyId);
localStorage.setItem("key_list",keyId);
}


key_list.length = 0;


function readStorage() {
console.log(localStorage.getItem("key_list"));
keyId = localStorage.getItem("key_list");


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in localStorage you are only writing the latest keyId.

```
for (var j in key_list) {
...
localStorage.setItem("key_list",keyId);
}
```

What you can do is to save an array to string of the keys like so:

```
for (var j in key_list) {
...
keyIdArr.push(keyId)
localStorage.setItem("key_list",keyIdArr.toString());
}
```

Comment: hi i try this but how would i read back the array as the code im using console.log(localStorage.getItem('key_list')); only give me the lat number

Answer (score 0):

You've to extract the keys into an array and then put it in the `localStorage`.

One way to do it is:

```
localStorage.setItem('key_list', key_list.map(x => x.GetUserData().val))
```

Comment: hi i try this but how would i read back the array as the code im using console.log(localStorage.getItem('key_list')); only give me the lat number

Comment: console.log should print all the items in the array...did you check if the array stored in localStorage has multiple values?

Comment: You can view the localStorage in chrome dev tools under Application tag

Comment: hi yer when i check it only come up with [object Object] im try het to out put [1, 2, 3]